# Union 2 table that have not a same attribute in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm doing a SQL assignment and I found that one question ask me to union 2 table together but this two table isn't have a same attribute. The question will show below.

List the union of customers and employees. For the customers, list customer name (first and last) and contact (CustStreet, CustCity, CusState). For the employees, list employee name (first and last) and contact (EmpPhone and EmpEmail).

Ps. May be I'm misunderstand about the question.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm guessing you've misunderstood the question. The answer from RC will indeed return a union of the two tables without erroring, but I can't see how it's any use.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
SELECT CustFirstName, CustLastName, CustStreet, CustCity, CustState, NULL, NULL 
FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT EmpFirstName, EmpLastName, NULL, NULL, NULL, EmpPhone, EmpMail 
FROM Employees
```

Comment: I believe this is a wrong answer because it will leave empty fields, your teacher won't be pleased

Comment: Sorry about that I forgot to tell you about attribute in each table.In customer have only street city state while in employee have only phone and email.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid question because both have the same resulting columns: Customer Name and Contact.  You can use inline view and aliases to do this.

E.g. (oracle sql syntax)

```
select FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME CUSTOMER_NAME, CUST_STREET || ', ' || CUST_CITY || ', ' || CUST_STATE CONTACT from SOME_TABLE
union
select FIRST_NAME || ' ' || LAST_NAME CUSTOMER_NAME, EMP_PHONE || ', ' || EMP_EMAIL CONTACT from SOME_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a union whitouth problems if the type of the merged columns are the same... so you can left a column empty usin a empty string or a null value

```
Select CustomerFirst + ' ' + CustomerLast, CustStreet, CustCity, CusState,'','' from Customers
union all
Select EmployeeFirst + ' ' + EmployeeLast, '','','', EmpPhone, EmpEmail from Employees
```

**Note**: Not Tested.

Answer (score 0):

On the `customers` selection just add empty default fields with

```
null as EmpPhone, null as EmpEmail
```

and then the same for `CustStreet, CustCity, CusState`

Be aware the the fields have to be on the same position in the queries of a union.

Answer (score 0):

You can select Null values out as part of your UNION selects. SO select NULL for the two Employee fields that don't exist in Custmer and NUll for each of the 3 Customer fields that don't exist in Employee
eg.

```
SELECT C.FirstName, C.LastName, C.CustStreet, C.CustCity, C.CustState, NULL, NULL FROM Customers C
UNION ALL
SELECT E.FirstName, E.LastName, NULL, NULL, NULL, E.EmpPhone, E.EmpEmail FROM Employees E
```